# GUI and Threads in a chat program

Tags: multithreading, user-interface, chat, javafx

Hello guys ive been searching for an answer to this question and was unable to find a suiting solution to my problem.

i have a chat program that has a somewhat advanced gui. The chat program in total consists of two programs a server and a client. ive created a protocol that my clients listens to and reacts depending on what type information it gets.

i have created a class called clientReciver which extends Thread. but i am now confused on how i will get the informaiton that the thread recives and use it in my gui.

and example of this could be how will i get the text that one of my clients sends and add it to my GUI?

It may be worth mentioning that i am using JavaFx Scenebuilder to build my GUI.

Hope someone is able to help be

Best Regards Marc Rasmussen

Comment: Please help mé im Really lost on this one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to advise without details on your custom protocol.  See the zenjava blog for some [inspiration](http://www.zenjava.com/2011/11/03/client-server-with-javafx-2-and-hessian-guice-fxml/).

Use a [Task](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html) to invoke your server from your client.  If the result of the client server call is synchronous get the [value](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html#getValue%28%29) returned by the call when the task completes.  If the call is asynchronous or the server pushes data to the client, set up a listener on the client running in it's own thread and when it gets a result invoke [Platform.runLater](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#runLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29) to feed the result to the JavaFX application thread for UI processing.

Comment: Okay ive never used the Task class before but i certainly see some potential in it. My questions is, should i run the thread in another class and then for instance add the String to a list and then collect that list from the GUI or how does that task thing work? im really glad for your answer by the way im just not 100% sure i know what you mean maybe because i am not skilled enough yet or do not know the methods that you advice me to use.

Comment: Have a look at this [example](https://gist.github.com/2305098) of adding strings to a collected list in a Task and the JavaFX [threading tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/threads/jfxpub-threads.htm) as well as the zenjava blog I linked to previously.

Comment: Thank you for your response just to get this right it seems that in examples they have the Thread in the Gui code instead of in a seperate class is this preferable?

Comment: Whether the server thread encapsulated in it's own class or an inner class instance is a personal preference and code style thing, technically it does not matter.